# Numpy fft function giving output different from the dft calculated using formula

Tags: python, numpy, signal-processing, fft, dft

I am trying to implement dft in python. I am using the standard formula:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
k = np.array([np.arange(-50, 50)])
fs, xn = wavfile.read('voice_recording.wav')
nbits = 16
max_nbits = float(2**(nbits-1))
xn = xn / (max_nbits + 1.0)
xn = np.expand_dims(xn[:,0], axis=1)
N = len(xn)
n = np.array([np.arange(0, N)])
Xk = np.sum(xn*np.exp(((-1j*2*math.pi)/N)*np.matmul(n.T, k)), axis=0)
```

Here, `xn` is an audio signal read from a .wav file ([voice_recording.wav](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jjHtHm-eESP20z4WaOT9A4svPRsvwYXd)). The code for FFT is:

```
Xk1 = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(xn, n=100, axis=0))
```

But both results are totally different, even though they should be same.
DFT plot:

[image]

And FFT plot:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `xn`? where is it defined?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux its a numpy array. It is read from .wav file

Comment: Your’re doing too many things in one line of code, it’s hard to see what it does and hard to debug. You should write your code so that it is easy to read. Next, look at intermediate results, make sure each one is as you expect. You’ll find your bug in no time that way.

Comment: @CrisLuengo well isn't using matrix calculation more efficient than Python loops. It uses C loops

Comment: I’m not suggesting to add loops. I’m suggesting to write shorter statements. There are too many brackets on one line to comfortably tell what is inside the call to `exp` and what is not! And you cannot check to see if the result of `np.matmul` is what you expect. Is the result of `np.exp` what you would expect? Right now you can’t tell if you run your code line by line. Split it up so you can see those intermediate results.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I tried doing that. All the values are as expected. I even tried with a loop. but still wrong answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without downloading your data file, I presume that it has more than 100 samples. If so, then

```
np.fft.fft(xn, n=100, axis=0)
```

cuts off the first 100 samples and computes the FFT on those. That is, it does not compute the same thing as your code.

When I use `xn = np.random.randn(100)`, and run your code, then both `Xk` and `Xk1` are identical up to `1e-13` or so. This indicates that your code is correct.

To compute only a subset of `k` values using the FFT algorithm, first compute the full transform, then discard the values you don't want. For example:

```
Xk1 = np.fft.fft(xn, axis=0)
Xk1 = np.fft.fftshift(Xk1)
Xk1 = Xk1[(N//2 - 50):(N//2 + 50)]
```

Comment: should the dimension of output be equal to k? as we are summing wrt n?

Comment: is the output of the function x[n] or x[k]?

Comment: @ShantanuShinde: Your code can compute the DFT for any `k`, it computes each one independently. It is the FFT algorithm that must compute them all at once. It cannot compute a subset. You would have to compute the whole thing (`fft(xn, axis=0)`) and then pick the 100 elements you want to look at.

Comment: when I take k and n equal, the output is matching the fft output. Well can you also suggest how to implement the fftshift myself?